# ontouchmove just fires once and for the first element (doesn't trigger other element's ontouchmove events)

Tags: javascript, android, events, triggers, touchmove

I am using Android to adapting one of my old JavaScript games, and I am wondering why the "touchmove" just fires for the first element I press with my finger. After pressing that element, I move the finger (without releasing it), and when I enter to another element that new element doesn't fire its "touchmove" event.

I made this simple example to test (it is not the actual code I am using it, but it still has the same behaviour):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:red; height:33%;" ontouchmove="this.style.background='black';">Box 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:blue; height:33%;" ontouchmove="this.style.background='black';">Box 2</div>
        <div style="background-color:orange; height:33%;" ontouchmove="this.style.background='black';">Box 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried that code on Android's default browser (Samsung Galaxy S3). I start pressing with my finger on "Box 1" (and it becomes black because the event is executed) and then, without releasing the finger, I continue moving it through "Box 2" and "Box 3" but they never get black because their event is never triggered.

What I would expect is a similar behaviour as "mousemove" event on Desktop browsers. You can test the following code on any desktop browser with JavaScript enabled:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:red; height:33%;" onmousemove="this.style.background='black';">Box 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:blue; height:33%;" onmousemove="this.style.background='black';">Box 2</div>
        <div style="background-color:orange; height:33%;" onmousemove="this.style.background='black';">Box 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you move the mouse over the elements, all become black. What doesn't it happen when I am using ontouchmove?

By the way, I am aware of the Android bug that needs to use "preventDefault()". I tried to use preventDefault method of the event on my actual game code but it still does the same.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
 Joan

Comment: I think you want on hover or something like that. If I recall correctly OnTouchMove triggers with x,y coordinate on where you touch down, then again with where you stop after dragging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But onhover doesn't exist, and the closest one is onmouseover but it doesn't work on Android with my examples :(

Comment: You could create an onTouchListener for the whole screen, check where it is via size rectangles, then set the background color on an object if the coordinates hit inside the rectange.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to use that way but I will finally use it because it seems the unique way.